# Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" URLs no longer working?

Tags: google-search

In the past, adding `&btnl` to a google search URL would turn it into an "I'm feeling lucky" search, which would redirect you straight to the first result.

I.e. http://www.google.com/search?q=facebook&btnl

If I click that now, I only get to the search result page. Has something changed? Is it forever disabled, or did the just change something in the way it works?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace your last <kbd>l</kbd> (lower case `L`) with <kbd>I</kbd> (upper case `I`).

Like for facebook write `http://www.google.com/search?q=facebook&btnI`

Comment: I believe the appropriate expression is "herp derp". Thanks!

Comment: Since I like to use DuckDuckGo now instead of Google, I was glad to find [this tip](https://www.reddit.com/r/duckduckgo/comments/1wgq4j/psa_im_feeling_lucky_on_duckduckgocom/) about putting a `!` at the beginning of a query, like I'm now using for a Brave/Chrome "custom search engine" to search Redfin: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!%20redfin+%s&t=brave&ia=web&btnI

Answer (score 4):

This works

`http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=facebook`

Admittedly it is no where near as short.

However if you use Google Chrome you can set your default search i.e searching via the address bar to use the "I'm feeling lucky" search as default.

- Open the Options Menu (Wrench>>Options)
- In the "Default Search:" section click on the "Manage" button
- Click the "Add" button
- Fill in the the blank text fields calling the search whatever you want
- In the URL field paste the following string:
  http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%s&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&aq=f&oq=
- Click the "OK" button
- Select the newly made Search from the Window
- Click the "Make Default" button
- Close out of the options

[Source Article - Google Chrome Forums](http://www.google.pl/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1dd75d14c52c044c&hl=en)

Comment: Adding `&sourceid=navclient` was enough, I guess I rushed to conclusions

Comment: Your problem is with `l` and `I`. See [my answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8885/googles-im-feeling-lucky-urls-no-longer-working/8890#8890).