# URL format for Google's I'm Feeling Lucky

Tags: google-search

I have 3 or 4 keywords I want to send from my PHP page to Google and return one page as if I had gone on to Google's site and searched using "I'm feeling lucky."

Does anyone know how to supply the keywords to Google?

What is the format?

e.g.:

```
www.google.co.uk/lucky?keywords="the royal family"
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950941/is-there-a-consistent-way-to-link-to-google-i-feel-lucky-result

Comment: This question was posted before the launch of Web Applications SE (the site private beta started at the end of Jun 2010, and this question is from February). It's unclear what the OP wanted to say by."send from by PHP page to Google". This is relevant because creating / developing web apps has been off-topic since the site early days of this site. On the other hand, things have changed a lot since 2010.

Comment: Related: [Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" URLs no longer working?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8885/88163), [Google's "I'm feeling lucky" URL](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/53554/88163), [Why doesn't Google's “I'm Feeling Lucky” feature work in this specific case?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/29992/88163)

Answer (score 53):

> http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&btnI

Replace "stackoverflow" with your keywords.

Comment: Stripped to the bare minimum :)

Comment: I saw that "I am lucky button" has name=btnI, I wonder how did you know that it should be written to web site adress by appending to the end?

Comment: Actually I inpected with Fiddler to see what URL was being requested upon clicking the "Feeling Lucky" button. Then I stripped all the obvious redundant parameters like language, source, etc from the URL, until I couldn't strip anymore.

Comment: Nice. That is the perfect answer!

Answer (score 15):

Like this:

```
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q={searchTerms}&btnI=I
```

`I` stands for **I**nstant.

Comment: Why doesn't the **I** stand for "I'm feeling lucky?"

Comment: it does (it is the name of the button) put the browser removed everything after the `'`

Comment: The name `btnI` comes from Google.

Answer (score 6):

The URL you'd need is:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=SEARCHTERM&btnI=I'm+Feeling+Lucky
```

where "SEARCHTERM" is the keyword you search for.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=the+royal+family&btnI=I

Replace "the+royal+family" with your url encoded search term.

Comment: It's been a while but in case it helps other users... If you want to use this in Firefox keyword.URL setting for instance, you have to let the &q parameter at the end of the url, this way : `http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I&q=`

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the query at the end:

http://www.google.com/search?btnI&q=stackexchange

Comment: Some time after 2008, it must have *www.* in order to work. For example  https://google.com/search?btnI&q=stackexchange does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following syntaxes:

1.
http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&btnI

But sometimes it's not predictable and it's giving you search results instead.

2.
http://www.google.com/webhp?#q=stackexchange+feeling+lucky&btnI

But sometimes you'll see some source code appearing in the second example, but you can ignore it.

---

`btnI` parameter is for Google Instant Enabled and `btn` is for Google Instant Disabled.