# How can I avoid Google's redirection notice, when feeling lucky?

Tags: google-search, google, browser-addons

Since a few months, Google's previous "I'm feeling lucky" URLs, e.g.,

> http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&btnI

(taken from [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/10700/11539)), have all begun pointing to "Redirection notices", meaning that the first link above gets redirected to

> https://www.google.it/url?q=https://stackoverflow.com/

instead of https://stackoverflow.com/. This does not happen when clicking *I'm feeling lucky* on Google's main search page, as it's implemented via Javascript; however, it does happen with all browser search tools that relied on those URLs, so that you can't save time (and avoid Google Instant spying on your address bar) by using them.

Does anybody know if there's a workaround?