# Why doesn't Google's “I'm Feeling Lucky” feature work in this specific case?

Tags: google-search

Why does this work:

http://www.google.com/search?q=azure+ray+site:en.wikipedia.org&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky

And so does this:

(Note: loads YouTube video) http://www.google.com/search?q=azure+ray+rise&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky

But this doesn't:

http://www.google.com/search?q=azure+ray+rise+site:songmeanings.net&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky

Nor does this:

http://www.google.com/search?q=azure+ray+rise+songmeanings&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky

Can websites/domains disable Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" feature? Or what?

**[UPDATE]**

As mentioned in the comments, when both search queries that do not work using those URLs are typed in manually on the Google homepage 'I'm Feeling Lucky' does work (note that you will have to disable Google Instant to use the button). However, when I copy the resulting Google URL (captured using Firebug) and paste that in the location bar it still doesn't work. An example full URL is:

https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=azure+ray+rise+site%3Asongmeanings.net&oq=azure+ray+rise+site%3Asongmeanings.net&gs_l=hp.7...3487.3487.0.6936.1.1.0.0.0.0.139.139.0j1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.KclWi-RBGlo&btnI=1

Comment: It worked for me when I copied the search terms into a new search and clicked "I'm Feeling Lucky".

Comment: @amiregelz interestingly enough that works for me as well, however when I copy the resulting Google URL (captured using Firebug) and paste that in the location bar it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed the question ["Google's “I'm Feeling Lucky” URLs no longer working?"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8885/googles-im-feeling-lucky-urls-no-longer-working?rq=1) under related in the right navigation bar. [The second answer to that question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/8888/23294) offered a working solution: add the querystring parameter `sourceid=navclient` (navclient is a reference to the Google Toolbar):

https://www.google.com/search?q=azure+ray+rise+site:songmeanings.net&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&sourceid=navclient

**[UPDATE]**

Apparently having your `Referer` set to `*.google.com` also works. The [links in this post of mine](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/websearch/how-do-iusing-google-search/G_hz65H0qNs%5B1-25%5D) on the Google Product forums all work as long because the referer being sent with the request.