# Use I'm-Feeling-Lucky type URL on 3rd party website

Tags: google-search, url, special-characters

An answer to [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53554/googles-im-feeling-lucky-url?newreg=4655be29580745188b7a104ae0cb8df9) post explains that it is possible to use a URL to link somebody to the first web page in a Google Search result, like "*I'm feeling lucky*" does. For example `https://www.google.com/search?btnI=I&q=your+query` will take you to the first search result for "*your query*".

I want to do a similar thing for the search engine on a particular website:  [culpa.info](http://culpa.info/). Culpa has a search engine of its own, and I want to be able to link someone to the first result of a search query.

I've attempted the same thing as with Google by using: `http://www.culpa.info/search?q=mdes` 
but no search is even attempted. I am given the prompt:

> Please search for something a bit more substantial.

I only get the same result when using the actual search bar if I use a character like "`@`" or "`$`" or some other special characters. This also happens if the search bar is blank and you hit "search".

Why might this be happening?

Is it because I am using the wrong encoding or something?

How could I change my URL so that Culpa would successfully return the first result of the query for a search for `mdes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that the search URL has to be constructed this way:

```
http://www.culpa.info/search?search=mdes
```

The other part is that unless their search engine has a feature to just return the first record from a search, you're not going to be able to do what you want. "I'm feeling lucky" is a feature of Google Search. Search engines don't all have the same features.

I don't even think they're using a search engine; it looks like it's just a simple database query on the back-end.

You'll need to direct your question/feature request to the managers of the site.